# Writing text with alphablending on a Bitmap

Tags: image, delphi, image-processing, bitmap, watermark

I want to create a text watermark on a photo.

So, I need to render text from label without any background colors on a Bitmap and than blend this bitmap by alpha blending.

I'm trying to use `Canvas.textOut` method, but the result is not what I expected. Text on the bitmap always has a white background.

How can I create a bitmap with the alpha channel, which has only text?

Comment: I would suggest you to use AGG library, some other people GR32_Text (in a while :-) and a few maybe GDI+... For simple alpha blended text with my favorite you might do it e.g. [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/rhkx0317) (surely there are many, many options you can tweak).

Comment: Did you try to use SetBkMode(Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT)?

Comment: set Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear, or call SetBkMode(Canvas.Handle, TRANSPARENT) directly.

Comment: @Glen, now the rest; how to alpha blend that text...:-) You'd need to have a bitmap which is transparent except that text and then alpha blend this bitmap over the original image. From my experience, this has always had ugly glitches around edges, not counting the effort you've needed to put into making it. Hence my suggestion about something more advanced than GDI.

Comment: @TLama could you show please an example, how can I use a GDI?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any. I didn't ever tried to make a bitmap with rendered text transparent all around. Edges around that text would look crappy; they'll always be with pure GDI (and to write a smooth edge calculation I've been lazy). My suggestion is not to use GDI. It will save you time and frustration from the result.

Comment: @TLama Ok, thanks. Could you tell me please, how can I install on my Delphi XE3 the AGG library? I'm never tried to install libraries/components before.

Comment: You don't actually have to install it. You can just grab a copy of it (I would strongly suggest you to use [`this one`](http://aggpasmod.sourceforge.net)) link source units directories to your project (in project options' search path), copy/paste my code from there and run...

Comment: @TLama I've tried to change the font name from fontdialog component like this aggEngine.Font(PChar(FontDialog1.Font.Name),45,false,false,fcVector), but nothing happen, the font still the same. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you using Delphi 2009 or above ?

Comment: Then you must typecast `TFont.Name` to ANSI string because the `TAgg2DGraphics.Font` method takes pointer to an ANSI string as the first paremeter and you're pointing there to a Unicode string. Do it like this instead `AggEngine.Font(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(FontDialog1.Font.Name)), 45, False, False, fcVector)`.